# Series manipulations in working out a Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

While I was working out a Laurent series of ${z^2 -2z+3 \over z-2}$ in the region $|z-1|>1$, I got stuck on a couple of things...

${z^2 - 2z +3 \over z-2} = {(z-1)^2 + 2 \over z-1}\cdot {z-1 \over z-2}\\
= {(z-1)^2 + 2 \over z-1} \cdot {1 \over 1 - {1 \over z-1}}\\
= \left[(z-1) + {2 \over z-1}\right] \cdot \left[1 + {1 \over z-1} + {1 \over (z-1)^2} + \dots \right]\\
= [(z-1) + 1 + 1/(z-1) + 1/(z-1)^2 + ...] + [ 2/(z-1) + 2/(z-1)^2 + ...] \qquad(a)\\
= (z-1) + 1 + [3/(z-1) + 3/(z-1)^2 + ...] \qquad(b)$

So what properties of complex series allows me to multiply each term of $1+1/(z-1) +\dots$ by $(z-1)$ and again each term of $1+1/(z-1)+\dots$ by $2/(z-1)$ to get $(a)$?

Also what properties of complex series allows me to add the terms together (like $1/(z-1)+2/(z-1)= 3/(z-1)$) to get $(b)$?

Is it absolute convergence? I have  no idea! Unfortunately I just do these manipulations instinctively and no textbook seems to tell me!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also if someone could point out to me where I can learn and format MathJax, I would be very grateful. It seems that every time I ask a question, it doesn't format!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please check over my [edit]s to ensure I haven't changed any parts of your question and feel free to convert expressions into fractional forms or remove the fractions as you please.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: For multiplying a series by a number and adding two convergent series you need nothing more than convergence of the series involved. Your computation is perfectly logical

Comment: My issue is with multiplying 1+1/(z-1)+... by, say 2/(z-1). Is 2/(z-1) just a complex number or is it a function?